# Python timestamp and event creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I would like some advise/ help please.
I have a list of lists (see below).
Each internal list is made up of [Timestamp, 'Event name']
If event is same but difference between timestamp is more than 2 minutes. It needs to be a seperate event with same name.

What I want to do is create something like below.

```
[Event1 - Timestamp_start to Timestamp_end]
[Event2 - Timestamp_start to Timestamp_end]
[Event1 - Timestamp_start to Timestamp_end]
[Event3 - Timestamp_start to Timestamp_end]
[Event4 - Timestamp_start to Timestamp_end]
[Event2 - Timestamp_start to Timestamp_end]
[Event1 - Timestamp_start to Timestamp_end]
```

I would appreciate if anyone can guide me through this.

Thank you in advance,
Best regards,

Shashank

```
'''

    list = [[1623690240.0, 'Event 2'], [1623690240.0, 'Event 1'], [1623690360.0, 'Event 2'], [1623690360.0, 'Event 1'], [1623690480.0, 'Event 2'], [1623690480.0, 'Event 1'], [1623690600.0, 'Event 2'], [1623690600.0, 'Event 1'], [1623690720.0, 'Event 1'], [1623690840.0, 'Event 1'], [1623690960.0, 'Event 1'], [1623691080.0, 'Event 1'], [1623691200.0, 'Event 1'], [1623691320.0, 'Event 3'], [1623691320.0, 'Event 1'], [1623691440.0, 'Event 4'], [1623691440.0, 'Event 1'], [1623691560.0, 'Event 4'], [1623691560.0, 'Event 1'], [1623691680.0, 'Event 4'], [1623691680.0, 'Event 1'], [1623691800.0, 'Event 4'], [1623691800.0, 'Event 1'], [1623691920.0, 'Event 4'], [1623691920.0, 'Event 1'], [1623692040.0, 'Event 1'], [1623692160.0, 'Event 1'], [1623692280.0, 'Event 1'], [1623692400.0, 'Event 1'], [1623692520.0, 'Event 1'], [1623692640.0, 'Event 1'], [1623692760.0, 'Event 1'], [1623692880.0, 'Event 1'], [1623693000.0, 'Event 7'], [1623693000.0, 'Event 1'], [1623693120.0, 'Event 7'], [1623693120.0, 'Event 1'], [1623693240.0, 'Event 7'], [1623693240.0, 'Event 1'], [1623693360.0, 'Event 7'], [1623693360.0, 'Event 1'], [1623693480.0, 'Event 7'], [1623693480.0, 'Event 1'], [1623693600.0, 'Event 7'], [1623693600.0, 'Event 1'], [1623693720.0, 'Event 1'], [1623693840.0, 'Event 1'], [1623693960.0, 'Event 1'], [1623694080.0, 'Event 1'], [1623694200.0, 'Event 1'], [1623694320.0, 'Event 5'], [1623694320.0, 'Event 1'], [1623694440.0, 'Event 5'], [1623694440.0, 'Event 1'], [1623694560.0, 'Event 5'], [1623694560.0, 'Event 1'], [1623694680.0, 'Event 5'], [1623694680.0, 'Event 1'], [1623694800.0, 'Event 5'], [1623694800.0, 'Event 1'], [1623694920.0, 'Event 5'], [1623694920.0, 'Event 1'], [1623695040.0, 'Event 1'], [1623695160.0, 'Event 1'], [1623695280.0, 'Event 1'], [1623695400.0, 'Event 1'], [1623695520.0, 'Event 1'], [1623695640.0, 'Event 1'], [1623695760.0, 'Event 1'], [1623695880.0, 'Event 1'], [1623696000.0, 'Event 1'], [1623696120.0, 'Event 1'], [1623696240.0, 'Event 1'], [1623696360.0, 'Event 1'], [1623696480.0, 'Event 1'], [1623696600.0, 'Event 1'], [1623696720.0, 'Event 1'], [1623696840.0, 'Event 1'], [1623696960.0, 'Event 1'], [1623697080.0, 'Event 1'], [1623697200.0, 'Event 1'], [1623697320.0, 'Event 1'], [1623697440.0, 'Event 1'], [1623697560.0, 'Event 1'], [1623697680.0, 'Event 1'], [1623697800.0, 'Event 1'], [1623697920.0, 'Event 1'], [1623698040.0, 'Event 1'], [1623698160.0, 'Event 1'], [1623698280.0, 'Event 1'], [1623698400.0, 'Event 1'], [1623698520.0, 'Event 1'], [1623698640.0, 'Event 1'], [1623698760.0, 'Event 1'], [1623698880.0, 'Event 1'], [1623699000.0, 'Event 1'], [1623699120.0, 'Event 1'], [1623699240.0, 'Event 1'], [1623699360.0, 'Event 1'], [1623699480.0, 'Event 1'], [1623699600.0, 'Event 1'], [1623699720.0, 'Event 1'], [1623699840.0, 'Event 1'], [1623699960.0, 'Event 1'], [1623700080.0, 'Event 1'], [1623700200.0, 'Event 1'], [1623700320.0, 'Event 1'], [1623700440.0, 'Event 1'], [1623700560.0, 'Event 1'], [1623700680.0, 'Event 1'], [1623700800.0, 'Event 1'], [1623700920.0, 'Event 1'], [1623701040.0, 'Event 1'], [1623701160.0, 'Event 1'], [1623701280.0, 'Event 1'], [1623701400.0, 'Event 1'], [1623701520.0, 'Event 1'], [1623701640.0, 'Event 1'], [1623701760.0, 'Event 1'], [1623701880.0, 'Event 1'], [1623702000.0, 'Event 1'], [1623702120.0, 'Event 1'], [1623702240.0, 'Event 1'], [1623702360.0, 'Event 1'], [1623702480.0, 'Event 1'], [1623702600.0, 'Event 1'], [1623702720.0, 'Event 1'], [1623702840.0, 'Event 1'], [1623702960.0, 'Event 1'], [1623703080.0, 'Event 1'], [1623703200.0, 'Event 1'], [1623703320.0, 'Event 1'], [1623703440.0, 'Event 1'], [1623703560.0, 'Event 1'], [1623703680.0, 'Event 1'], [1623703800.0, 'Event 1'], [1623703920.0, 'Event 1'], [1623704040.0, 'Event 1'], [1623704160.0, 'Event 1'], [1623704280.0, 'Event 1'], [1623704400.0, 'Event 1'], [1623704520.0, 'Event 1'], [1623704640.0, 'Event 1'], [1623704760.0, 'Event 1'], [1623704880.0, 'Event 1'], [1623705000.0, 'Event 1'], [1623705120.0, 'Event 1'], [1623705240.0, 'Event 1'], [1623705360.0, 'Event 1'], [1623705480.0, 'Event 1'], [1623705600.0, 'Event 1'], [1623705720.0, 'Event 1'], [1623705840.0, 'Event 1'], [1623705960.0, 'Event 1'], [1623706080.0, 'Event 1'], [1623706200.0, 'Event 1'], [1623706320.0, 'Event 1'], [1623706440.0, 'Event 1'], [1623706560.0, 'Event 1'], [1623706680.0, 'Event 1'], [1623706800.0, 'Event 1'], [1623706920.0, 'Event 1'], [1623707040.0, 'Event 1'], [1623707160.0, 'Event 1'], [1623707280.0, 'Event 1'], [1623707400.0, 'Event 1'], [1623707520.0, 'Event 1'], [1623707640.0, 'Event 1'], [1623707760.0, 'Event 1'], [1623707880.0, 'Event 1'], [1623708000.0, 'Event 1'], [1623708120.0, 'Event 1'], [1623708240.0, 'Event 1'], [1623708360.0, 'Event 1'], [1623708480.0, 'Event 1'], [1623708600.0, 'Event 1'], [1623708720.0, 'Event 1'], [1623708840.0, 'Event 1'], [1623708960.0, 'Event 1'], [1623709080.0, 'Event 1'], [1623709200.0, 'Event 1'], [1623709320.0, 'Event 1'], [1623709440.0, 'Event 1'], [1623709560.0, 'Event 1'], [1623709680.0, 'Event 1'], [1623709800.0, 'Event 1'], [1623709920.0, 'Event 1'], [1623710040.0, 'Event 1'], [1623710160.0, 'Event 1'], [1623710280.0, 'Event 1'], [1623710400.0, 'Event 1'], [1623710520.0, 'Event 1'], [1623710640.0, 'Event 1'], [1623710760.0, 'Event 1'], [1623710880.0, 'Event 1'], [1623711000.0, 'Event 1'], [1623711120.0, 'Event 1'], [1623711240.0, 'Event 6'], [1623711240.0, 'Event 1'], [1623711360.0, 'Event 6'], [1623711360.0, 'Event 1'], [1623711480.0, 'Event 6'], [1623711480.0, 'Event 1'], [1623711600.0, 'Event 6'], [1623711600.0, 'Event 1'], [1623711720.0, 'Event 6'], [1623711720.0, 'Event 1'], [1623711840.0, 'Event 6'], [1623711840.0, 'Event 1']]

'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'am not sure if I understood your problem correctly. You want to get the start timestamp of an event and the end timestamp?

I modified two timestamps for event 2 to test with a larger difference. Your data, as I have seen, always had the same difference.

```
mylist = [[9623690240.0, 'Event 2'], [1623690240.0, 'Event 1'], [9623690360.0, 'Event 2'], [1623690360.0, 'Event 1'], [1623690480.0, 'Event 2'], [1623690480.0, 'Event 1'], [1623690600.0, 'Event 2'], [1623690600.0, 'Event 1'], [1623690720.0, 'Event 1'], [1623690840.0, 'Event 1'], [1623690960.0, 'Event 1'], [1623691080.0, 'Event 1'], [1623691200.0, 'Event 1'], [1623691320.0, 'Event 3'], [1623691320.0, 'Event 1'], [1623691440.0, 'Event 4'], [1623691440.0, 'Event 1'], [1623691560.0, 'Event 4'], [1623691560.0, 'Event 1'], [1623691680.0, 'Event 4'], [1623691680.0, 'Event 1'], [1623691800.0, 'Event 4'], [1623691800.0, 'Event 1'], [1623691920.0, 'Event 4'], [1623691920.0, 'Event 1'], [1623692040.0, 'Event 1'], [1623692160.0, 'Event 1'], [1623692280.0, 'Event 1'], [1623692400.0, 'Event 1'], [1623692520.0, 'Event 1'], [1623692640.0, 'Event 1'], [1623692760.0, 'Event 1'], [1623692880.0, 'Event 1'], [1623693000.0, 'Event 7'], [1623693000.0, 'Event 1'], [1623693120.0, 'Event 7'], [1623693120.0, 'Event 1'], [1623693240.0, 'Event 7'], [1623693240.0, 'Event 1'], [1623693360.0, 'Event 7'], [1623693360.0, 'Event 1'], [1623693480.0, 'Event 7'], [1623693480.0, 'Event 1'], [1623693600.0, 'Event 7'], [1623693600.0, 'Event 1'], [1623693720.0, 'Event 1'], [1623693840.0, 'Event 1'], [1623693960.0, 'Event 1'], [1623694080.0, 'Event 1'], [1623694200.0, 'Event 1'], [1623694320.0, 'Event 5'], [1623694320.0, 'Event 1'], [1623694440.0, 'Event 5'], [1623694440.0, 'Event 1'], [1623694560.0, 'Event 5'], [1623694560.0, 'Event 1'], [1623694680.0, 'Event 5'], [1623694680.0, 'Event 1'], [1623694800.0, 'Event 5'], [1623694800.0, 'Event 1'], [1623694920.0, 'Event 5'], [1623694920.0, 'Event 1'], [1623695040.0, 'Event 1'], [1623695160.0, 'Event 1'], [1623695280.0, 'Event 1'], [1623695400.0, 'Event 1'], [1623695520.0, 'Event 1'], [1623695640.0, 'Event 1'], [1623695760.0, 'Event 1'], [1623695880.0, 'Event 1'], [1623696000.0, 'Event 1'], [1623696120.0, 'Event 1'], [1623696240.0, 'Event 1'], [1623696360.0, 'Event 1'], [1623696480.0, 'Event 1'], [1623696600.0, 'Event 1'], [1623696720.0, 'Event 1'], [1623696840.0, 'Event 1'], [1623696960.0, 'Event 1'], [1623697080.0, 'Event 1'], [1623697200.0, 'Event 1'], [1623697320.0, 'Event 1'], [1623697440.0, 'Event 1'], [1623697560.0, 'Event 1'], [1623697680.0, 'Event 1'], [1623697800.0, 'Event 1'], [1623697920.0, 'Event 1'], [1623698040.0, 'Event 1'], [1623698160.0, 'Event 1'], [1623698280.0, 'Event 1'], [1623698400.0, 'Event 1'], [1623698520.0, 'Event 1'], [1623698640.0, 'Event 1'], [1623698760.0, 'Event 1'], [1623698880.0, 'Event 1'], [1623699000.0, 'Event 1'], [1623699120.0, 'Event 1'], [1623699240.0, 'Event 1'], [1623699360.0, 'Event 1'], [1623699480.0, 'Event 1'], [1623699600.0, 'Event 1'], [1623699720.0, 'Event 1'], [1623699840.0, 'Event 1'], [1623699960.0, 'Event 1'], [1623700080.0, 'Event 1'], [1623700200.0, 'Event 1'], [1623700320.0, 'Event 1'], [1623700440.0, 'Event 1'], [1623700560.0, 'Event 1'], [1623700680.0, 'Event 1'], [1623700800.0, 'Event 1'], [1623700920.0, 'Event 1'], [1623701040.0, 'Event 1'], [1623701160.0, 'Event 1'], [1623701280.0, 'Event 1'], [1623701400.0, 'Event 1'], [1623701520.0, 'Event 1'], [1623701640.0, 'Event 1'], [1623701760.0, 'Event 1'], [1623701880.0, 'Event 1'], [1623702000.0, 'Event 1'], [1623702120.0, 'Event 1'], [1623702240.0, 'Event 1'], [1623702360.0, 'Event 1'], [1623702480.0, 'Event 1'], [1623702600.0, 'Event 1'], [1623702720.0, 'Event 1'], [1623702840.0, 'Event 1'], [1623702960.0, 'Event 1'], [1623703080.0, 'Event 1'], [1623703200.0, 'Event 1'], [1623703320.0, 'Event 1'], [1623703440.0, 'Event 1'], [1623703560.0, 'Event 1'], [1623703680.0, 'Event 1'], [1623703800.0, 'Event 1'], [1623703920.0, 'Event 1'], [1623704040.0, 'Event 1'], [1623704160.0, 'Event 1'], [1623704280.0, 'Event 1'], [1623704400.0, 'Event 1'], [1623704520.0, 'Event 1'], [1623704640.0, 'Event 1'], [1623704760.0, 'Event 1'], [1623704880.0, 'Event 1'], [1623705000.0, 'Event 1'], [1623705120.0, 'Event 1'], [1623705240.0, 'Event 1'], [1623705360.0, 'Event 1'], [1623705480.0, 'Event 1'], [1623705600.0, 'Event 1'], [1623705720.0, 'Event 1'], [1623705840.0, 'Event 1'], [1623705960.0, 'Event 1'], [1623706080.0, 'Event 1'], [1623706200.0, 'Event 1'], [1623706320.0, 'Event 1'], [1623706440.0, 'Event 1'], [1623706560.0, 'Event 1'], [1623706680.0, 'Event 1'], [1623706800.0, 'Event 1'], [1623706920.0, 'Event 1'], [1623707040.0, 'Event 1'], [1623707160.0, 'Event 1'], [1623707280.0, 'Event 1'], [1623707400.0, 'Event 1'], [1623707520.0, 'Event 1'], [1623707640.0, 'Event 1'], [1623707760.0, 'Event 1'], [1623707880.0, 'Event 1'], [1623708000.0, 'Event 1'], [1623708120.0, 'Event 1'], [1623708240.0, 'Event 1'], [1623708360.0, 'Event 1'], [1623708480.0, 'Event 1'], [1623708600.0, 'Event 1'], [1623708720.0, 'Event 1'], [1623708840.0, 'Event 1'], [1623708960.0, 'Event 1'], [1623709080.0, 'Event 1'], [1623709200.0, 'Event 1'], [1623709320.0, 'Event 1'], [1623709440.0, 'Event 1'], [1623709560.0, 'Event 1'], [1623709680.0, 'Event 1'], [1623709800.0, 'Event 1'], [1623709920.0, 'Event 1'], [1623710040.0, 'Event 1'], [1623710160.0, 'Event 1'], [1623710280.0, 'Event 1'], [1623710400.0, 'Event 1'], [1623710520.0, 'Event 1'], [1623710640.0, 'Event 1'], [1623710760.0, 'Event 1'], [1623710880.0, 'Event 1'], [1623711000.0, 'Event 1'], [1623711120.0, 'Event 1'], [1623711240.0, 'Event 6'], [1623711240.0, 'Event 1'], [1623711360.0, 'Event 6'], [1623711360.0, 'Event 1'], [1623711480.0, 'Event 6'], [1623711480.0, 'Event 1'], [1623711600.0, 'Event 6'], [1623711600.0, 'Event 1'], [1623711720.0, 'Event 6'], [1623711720.0, 'Event 1'], [1623711840.0, 'Event 6'], [1623711840.0, 'Event 1']]

events = {}
for time, name in mylist:
    events.setdefault(name, []).append(time)

for name, times in sorted(events.items()):
    times = sorted(times)
    while times:
        last = times.pop(0)
        times_nearby = [last]
        while times and times[0] - last <= 2 * 60:
            last = times.pop(0)
            times_nearby.append(last)
        print(f"{name}: {min(times_nearby)} - {max(times_nearby)}")
```

Output:

```
Event 1: 1623690240.0 - 1623711840.0
Event 2: 1623690480.0 - 1623690600.0
Event 2: 9623690240.0 - 9623690360.0
Event 3: 1623691320.0 - 1623691320.0
Event 4: 1623691440.0 - 1623691920.0
Event 5: 1623694320.0 - 1623694920.0
Event 6: 1623711240.0 - 1623711840.0
Event 7: 1623693000.0 - 1623693600.0
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Yes, timestamp of start of event and end of event. The reason I can't use max, is because if difference between two timestamp for an event is more than 2 minutes, then it should be a new event with same name.

Comment: @isash I've updated my post. Maybe it will solve your problem now.

Comment: you are a Legend. Thank you so very much. :)

Comment: Good. If that answers your question, you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Then other people see that the problem has already been solved. :)